# The best way load files from Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, isolatedstorage

In my Windows Store App I save/use files (almost images) in Isolated Storage.
 When I need to present image i use following:

```
var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    obj.Image = new BitmapImage();
    await obj.Image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
```

But when I use 3+ images in same page I have lags.
 I'm looking for faster solution to access Isolated Storage files.

Comment: You need to spin the code off to a separate thread. You're blocking the UI thread which is giving you the lag you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start with this article [Optimize media resources (Windows Store apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh994642.aspx), and couple more things:

1. Make sure that if you show them in the ListView / GridView - you have enabled virtualization (you use right ItemsPanel which supports virtualization).
2. If you just need to load images from local storage - set the binding from Image.Source to to the right URI (ms-appx:/// or  ms-appdata:///local/), and Image control will do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're opening multiple images, but since all the methods are asynchronous you shouldn't iterate through your files sequentially, but open all of them in parallel.

So instead of doing this (where you're waiting for the previous image to load before starting to load the next one):

```
foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
{
    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        obj.Image = new BitmapImage();
        await obj.Image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

You should approach it like this:

```
// not sure about the type of obj
public async Task<Image> LoadImage(string fileName, dynamic obj)
{
    var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
    using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        obj.Image = new BitmapImage();
        await obj.Image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    }
}

var tasks = fileNames.Select(f => LoadImage(f, obj)).ToArray();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This will initialize an array of awaitable tasks loading the images and then await all of them at the same time so that they will execute in parallel.